# sorting value pairs with one pair being in dollar format in python

Tags: python, sorting, currency

so I have a list like this.

```
items = [('30-Apr-2018', '$0.14'), ('30-Apr-2018', '$1,534.77'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$7.34')]
```

I tried using these two commands to sort it which I think perform the same sorting

```
items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])
items = sorted(items,key=itemgetter(1))
```

But they keep getting out of order.  It looks like some sorting is done? But not correctly for some reason, which I suspect is due to the format of the second element in the list pair.  Any suggestions on how to sort this?  The only option that I see is to convert the dollar value to decimal then try sorting again, and maybe adding the dollar sign back, but maybe someone else would have a better solution.

The full list is here.
before sort =  [('30-Apr-2018', '$0.14'), ('30-Apr-2018', '$101.65'), ('30-Apr-2018', '$1,534.77'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$37.78'), ('29-Apr-2018', '$6.31'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$4.76'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$39.55'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$664.78'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$142.25'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$9.12'), ('27-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('27-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('26-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('26-Apr-2018', '-$13.23'), ('25-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('25-Apr-2018', '-$2.09'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$27.27'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$9.96'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$110.00'), ('23-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$87.02'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$5.41'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$21.11'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$12.69'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$6.75'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$500.00'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$15.67'), ('20-Apr-2018', '-$41.74'), ('20-Apr-2018', '-$20.47'), ('20-Apr-2018', '$31.60'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$2.09'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$5.24'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$22.70'), ('18-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$4.99'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('16-Apr-2018', '-$7.33'), ('16-Apr-2018', '-$59.00'), ('15-Apr-2018', '-$42.75'), ('14-Apr-2018', '-$9.43'), ('13-Apr-2018', '$1,545.79'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$11.63'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$14.44'), ('11-Apr-2018', '-$81.31'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$79.74'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$11.11'), ('09-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('07-Apr-2018', '-$72.42'), ('06-Apr-2018', '-$3.01'), ('06-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('05-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('05-Apr-2018', '-$9.20'), ('04-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$460.00'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('02-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('02-Apr-2018', '$289.04'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$6.30'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$7.50'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$13.28')]

after sort =  [('30-Apr-2018', '$0.14'), ('30-Apr-2018', '$1,534.77'), ('13-Apr-2018', '$1,545.79'), ('30-Apr-2018', '$101.65'), ('02-Apr-2018', '$289.04'), ('20-Apr-2018', '$31.60'), ('29-Apr-2018', '$6.31'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$11.11'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$11.63'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$110.00'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$12.69'), ('26-Apr-2018', '-$13.23'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$13.28'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$14.44'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$142.25'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$15.67'), ('25-Apr-2018', '-$2.09'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$2.09'), ('20-Apr-2018', '-$20.47'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$21.11'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$22.70'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$27.27'), ('06-Apr-2018', '-$3.01'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$37.78'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$39.55'), ('29-Apr-2018', '-$4.76'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$4.99'), ('20-Apr-2018', '-$41.74'), ('15-Apr-2018', '-$42.75'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$460.00'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$5.24'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$5.41'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$500.00'), ('16-Apr-2018', '-$59.00'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$6.30'), ('21-Apr-2018', '-$6.75'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$664.78'), ('16-Apr-2018', '-$7.33'), ('27-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('27-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('26-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('25-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('23-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('19-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('18-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('17-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('12-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('09-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('06-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('05-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('04-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('03-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('02-Apr-2018', '-$7.34'), ('01-Apr-2018', '-$7.50'), ('07-Apr-2018', '-$72.42'), ('10-Apr-2018', '-$79.74'), ('11-Apr-2018', '-$81.31'), ('22-Apr-2018', '-$87.02'), ('28-Apr-2018', '-$9.12'), ('05-Apr-2018', '-$9.20'), ('14-Apr-2018', '-$9.43'), ('24-Apr-2018', '-$9.96')]

Comment: As you can see, the -7.34 values are all grouped together, which implies some sorting is done...

Comment: sorting strings representing numbers can lead to unexpected results, just format your strings and convert to actual numbers before sorting...

Comment: ok thats what I thought, I'm trying to strip the $ sign now and I'm using this command    items = int(round(float(items[1::2].strip('$')) * 100)) but its giving me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sort your price, you first need to convert them in a numeric format (float or integer). So to convert your string, you need the following step:

1. Remove all the `","`
2. Check if the number is negative (start with `"-"`)
3. Convert to digits to `float`
4. Convert to `int`

You can use the following code:

```
def convert(string):
    string = string.replace(",","")
    num_val = 0.0
    if string[0]=="-":
        num_val = -float(string[2:])
    else:
        num_val = float(string[1:])
    # If you want integer value in cents
    # return int(round(num_val*100.0))
    return num_value

items = [(d, convert(p)) for (d,p) in items]
```

The result you get can be explained by the fact that when sorting string, you do it character by character and `"-" > "$"` so all the negative number are at the end and sorted in lexicographical order.

Comment: File "C:/Users/thomas/PycharmProjects/test/main/__init__.py", line 63, in <listcomp>
    items = [(d, convert(p)) for (d, p) in items]
  File "C:/Users/thomas/PycharmProjects/test/main/__init__.py", line 22, in convert
    num_val = float(string[1:])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: I tested in python3, with the items given in your post. It looks like one of your value is not in the correct format. Try adding a print at the start of the `convert` function

Comment: Ah, yes its working now.  I was scraping a webpage and it updated with the p value having a single digit 0, thanks for the pointer!  I guess I have to write another function to convert the decimal back to a $ format after its been sorted?  Right now its giving me numbers like this -66478, which should be -$664.78

Comment: is there a way to keep the decimal point in the original string?

Comment: I modified the code to keep float value. To convert back to string, look into python string formating and the format function.

Comment: I managed to change it back using this function

def convertback(int):
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'English_United States.1252')
    int = int/100.00
    if int < 0:
        int = int * -1
        int = locale.currency(int, grouping=True)
        int = '-' + int
    else:
        int = locale.currency(int, grouping=True)

    return int

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension for formatting / conversion:

```
items = [(date, float("".join(c for c in price if c!='$' and c!=','))) for date, price in items]
```

then just sort as intended...